# jquery ui: css scaled elements do not work with draggable()

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, scale, draggable

I'm trying to make CSS scaled objects work correct when using the draggable() method in jquery ui.

CSS:

```
#container{
  zoom: 2;
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #888;
}

#box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#box').draggable();
```

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/9zm486xu/1/

In the example above you'll notice that the scale factor affects the dragging behaviour, resulting in e.g. twice the mouse distance when scaling is set to 2.

Is there a way to make CSS scaled objects draggable as the user might expect it (to be always under the mouse)? I can use an approach where I calculate each object to be scaled and then apply it to the DOM, but scaling just the container (see example) would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {

    ui.position.left = ui.position.left / scale
    ui.position.top = ui.position.top / scale
  }
});
```

You can do something like this if you https://jsfiddle.net/9zm486xu/2/